# Invalid ELF header when using pyarmor library even though installation matches my architecture

Tags: python, pip, pyarmor

I'm trying to test `pyarmor` with

`echo "print(1)" > test.py`

`pyarmor gen test.py`

But am receiving the following error:

`ERROR    /usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyarmor/cli/core/pytransform3.so: invalid ELF header`

AFAIK, ELF header errors are typically due to architecture incompatibility with the installed library.. however my platform & specs inside the `ubuntu:23.04` container I'm building are:

```
root@513aa8169a6c:/# uname -a
Linux 513aa8169a6c 5.15.78-0-virt #1-Alpine SMP Fri, 11 Nov 2022 10:19:45 +0000 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I run `pip install -vvv pyarmor==8.0.1`, I can see the correct .whl for my architecture is being detected i.e. **py3-none-any.whl**.

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org:443 "GET /packages/2d/47/fa465e1d7712816320928b9a27b7d7dc1a3f90f800f9c3b064f8eacc7578/pyarmor-8.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl HTTP/1.1" 200 207362
  Downloading pyarmor-8.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (207 kB)
```

So what is going wrong here?

Comment: What wheel for `pyarmor.cli.core` was installed? `pyarmor` itself is a pure Python wrapper around the architecture specific package that provides the `.so` file.

Comment: @chepner, this guy

`Added pyarmor.cli.core~=1.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/31/d91f73a2914c95f1f0bdad55cf09d2e33d3b2f0a18517ee1881ea4e6a666/pyarmor.cli.core-1.0-cp311-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

Comment: I should add, this is inside a `ubuntu:23.04` container

Comment: `uname` mentions Alpine, not Ubuntu.

Comment: `FROM ubuntu:23.04` this is the image I'm pulling

Comment: Can you reproduce this using `ubuntu:22.04`? 23.04 hasn't even been released for public testing yet, AFAIK.

Comment: With `grep -E '^(VERSION|NAME)=' /etc/os-release`, VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"... and same error unfortunately